# How to create a GenericGraph based on ExVertex and ExEdge with Graphs.jl in julia?

Tags: julia, graph-theory

I am a new user of Julia and I want to work on graphs. I found the Graphs.jl library but not very documented. I tried to create a GenericGraph based on ExVertex and ExEdge but I need more information.

The code I'm using :

```
using Graphs

CompGraph = GenericGraph{ExVertex, ExEdge{ExVertex}}


temp = ExVertex(1, "VertexName")
temp.attributes["Att"] = "Test"

add_vertex!(CompGraph, temp)
```

Now I still need the ExVertex list and ExEdge list. Is there any defined parameters? or how can I create such lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was too simple. a list is juste a simple array and not a new type. Besides, there is a simple defined function which creates graphs based on different types of edges and vertecies.

I changed my code to :

```
using Graphs

CG_VertexList = ExVertex[]
CG_EdgeList = ExEdge{ExVertex}[]

CompGraph = graph(CG_VertexList, CG_EdgeList)

temp = ExVertex(1, "VertexName")
temp.attributes["Att"] = "Test"

add_vertex!(CompGraph, temp)
```